# ArcMap v10 - Polygon Layer - Keeping one polygon above another

Tags: arcgis-10.0, shapefile

I have a shapefile with polygons of differing colors.  I am using a white hash pattern to represent partial ownership.

In short - Polygon #1 is Green and Polygon #2 is a White Hash pattern.

**Problem:** The Hash Pattern is not staying on "top" of the Color Pattern.

What do I need to do to keep the hash pattern on "top"?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to do this under the symbology tab in the layers property. To the right are up and down arrows that let you rearange your polygons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

symbol levels will accomplish what you need.
In layer properties look in the lower right for "advanced".

[image: sym lev]

Turn it on and move your categories up and down to accomplish needed results.